# Showing the almost everywhere equality of two unions of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Sorry for the ambiguous title. I am trying to prove this seemingly simple statement.

Let $\{A_i\}$ and $\{B_i\}$ be sequences of measurable sets in a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $\mu(A_i\triangle B_i) = 0$. Then the following holds
$$\mu((\cup A_i) \triangle (\cup B_i)) = \mu((\cap A_i) \triangle (\cap B_i))=0$$

By hypothesis $\mu(A_i\setminus B_i) = \mu(B_i\setminus A_i) = 0$. But when I expand $((\cup A_i) \setminus (\cup B_i))$ and $((\cup B_i) \setminus (\cup A_i))$ I get cross terms like $(A_i\setminus B_j)$ with $i\neq j$. I don't know how to handle those. I feel like I shouldn't start with expanding the set difference of the unions but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $$ \left( \bigcup_i A_i \right) \Delta \left( \bigcup_i B_i \right) = C_1 \cup C_2$$

where $$\begin{align*} C_1 &:= \left( \bigcup_i A_i \right)  \backslash \left( \bigcup_j B_j \right) = \bigcup_i \left( A_i \backslash \bigcup_j B_j \right) \subseteq \bigcup_i A_i \backslash B_i \\ C_2 &:=  \left( \bigcup_i B_i \right)  \backslash \left( \bigcup_j A_j \right)  =\bigcup_i \left( B_i \backslash  \bigcup_j A_j  \right) \subseteq \bigcup_{i} B_i \backslash A_i. \end{align*}$$

Thus, $$\left( \bigcup_i A_i \right) \Delta \left( \bigcup_i B_i \right)  \subseteq \bigcup_i (A_i \Delta B_i).$$

Use a similar argumentation for the second one.

Comment: Thank you saz. I will just put the answer here for the second one as well for future reference for myself.
$$\bigcap_j A_j \setminus \bigcap_i B_i = \left(\bigcap_j A_j\right) \bigcap \left(\bigcap_i B_i\right)^\mathsf{c} = \left(\bigcap_j A_j\right) \bigcap \left(\bigcup_i B_i^\mathsf{c}\right)= \bigcup_i\left(\left(\bigcap_j A_j\right) \bigcap B_i^\mathsf{c} \right) = \bigcup_i\left(\left(\bigcap_j A_j\right) \setminus B_i \right) \subseteq \bigcup_i\left(A_i \setminus B_i \right) $$